# Scala: how to call method without tuple argument?

Tags: scala, tuples, overloading

I have two methods to add elements to a customized collection:

```
class WrappedMap[A, B] {
  protected var a2b = Map[A, B]()

  def +=(a: A, b: B) = {
    a2b += a -> b
    this
  }

  def +=(t: (A,B)): this.type = {
    this.+=(t._1, t._2)
  }
  def ++=(t: Iterable[(A,B)]) = {
    (this /: t){ case (b, elem) => b += elem }
  }
}

val c = new WrappedMap[Int, Int]
c ++= Seq((1, 2),(2, 4))
```

It throws a Stackoverflow exception because the call to the `+=` inside `++=` calls the `+=`, which in turns call itself instead of calling the first variant.

How can I change the call in the body of the second `+=` so that it calls the first one?

Comment: I can't type a full fledged answer ATM but add the return type to your first `+=` definition. It's a known quirk that scala has trouble determining which overloaded method to call without them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the specification of `this.type` as the return type from the second form of `+=`. Not sure the exact reason but the compiler does not recognise the first form as returning `this.type` therefore it can't be used to satisfy the return type of the second form. I recreated it with:

```
case class Foo[A,B](s: String) {

  def bar(a: String, b: String) = {
    this.copy(s"a: $a b: $b")
  }

  def bar(c: (String, String)): this.type = {
    this.bar (c._1, c._2)
  }

}

val f = Foo("")

f bar (("hello", "world"))
```

Instead, you can just use the class and type params as the return type:

```
case class Foo[A, B](s: String) {

  def bar(a: String, b: String) : Foo[A,B] = {
    this.copy(s"a: $a b: $b")
  }

  def bar(c: (String, String)): Foo[A, B] = {
    this.bar (c._1, c._2)
  }

}

val f = Foo[Int, Long]("")

f bar (("hello", "world"))
```

Or, where inheritance needs to be supported:

```
class Foo[A, B] {

  private var s: String = ""

  def bar(a: String, b: String) : this.type = {
    s = s"a: $a b: $b"
    this
  }

  def bar(c: (String, String)): this.type = {
    this.bar (c._1, c._2)
  }
}

case object Foo2 extends Foo[Int, Long]

Foo2 bar (("hello", "world"))
```

Comment: This is a workaround. However, in my class, it is not a case class and can be extended, thus I need to return the same type. And I don't need F-bounded polymorphism which would be way too complicated

Comment: OK so then use `this.type` in both cases

Comment: Can you please summarize your answer ? You have three time the same code with variations. Better is to answer the OP's problem in its context.